# web browser automation for interacting with Google

Tags: automation, webbrowser-app

I won't bother with too many details but I need to programatically click on elements on a webpage. https://keep.google.com/ to be exact. For various reasons I cannot use things like iMacros or Greasemonkey userscripts.

If I was on Windows then I could use VBA to interact with the IE window.

I'm wondering if there is something similar to this for Ubuntu/Linux for Chrome or FireFox or some browser?

I'm hoping for a scripting language like Python, Perl, Bash, or JavaScript.

Just some way I can load a page and then interact with the DOM and invoke events like click and keyboard.

Comment: You could expand on "For various reasons I cannot use things like iMacros or Greasemonkey userscripts".

Comment: @DKBose: iMacros doesn't have IF conditions and userscripts won't let me do IsTrusted = true mouse events. Google won't let user JS interact with the page.

Comment: Take a look at Mechanize and BeautifulSoup but I'm not sure that's what you are asking for. They are Python libraries to emulate a web browser.

Comment: Are the elements always on the same position on the screen?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: No. So I'd need a way to be able to find elements using selectors or something and then finding their position.

Comment: @AshharHasan: Thanks but it doesn't look like either of them let me generate events like click. :/